# Rails doesn't render partial like it says it has

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My rails server says that it has rendered my partial in my page, but the content is not there.
Even when I inspect the elements on the page using Chrome DevTools, the div that is supposed to be rendered isn't there.

**EDIT:** Fixed that problem, but now the partial inside that partial won't render. I'll opena new question for that problem.

`show.html.erb` (with fix):

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<% provide(:pagetitle, @user.name) %>

<% render'layouts/relation' unless current_user?(@user)%>

<div id="stats">
    Player Statistics will appear here.
</div>

<div id="characters">
    Player Characters will appear here.
</div>
```

`_relation.html.erb` (the partial):

```
<div id="relation">
    <% if current_user.friends?(@user) %>
        <%= render 'layouts/edit_relation', locals: { action: "rm-friend" } %>
    <% elsif current_user.req_friends?(@user) %>
        Friend Request Pending...
    <% elsif current_user.pend_friends?(@user) %>
        <%= render 'layouts/edit_relation', locals: { action: "add-friend" } %>
        <%= render 'layouts/edit_relation', locals: { action: "rej-friend" } %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render 'layouts/edit_relation', locals: { action: "req-friend" } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

`_edit_relation.html.erb` (the partial within the partial):

```
<% case :action %>
    <% when "req-friend"%>
        <%= form_for(current_user.relation.build(character: @user.id, type: "freq"), remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :character %></div>
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :type %></div>
            <%= f.submit "Add Friend", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

    <% when "add-friend"%>
        <%= form_for(current_user.relation.build(character: @user.id, type: "friend"), remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :character %></div>
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :type %></div>
            <%= f.submit "Accept Request", class: "submit" %>
        <% end %>

    <% when "rej-friend" %>
        <%= form_for(current_user.reverse_relation.find_by(owner: @user.id, type: "freq"), html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.submit "Reject Request", class: "submit" %>
        <% end %>

    <% when "rm-friend"%>
        <%= form_for(current_user.reverse_relation.find_by(owner: @user.id, type: "friend"), html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.submit "Remove Friend", class: "submit" %>
        <% end %>

<% end %>
```

My server log that says that the partial has been rendered:

```
Started GET "/melv" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-01 21:22:21 +0000
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"melv"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token
" = '35599bfa491cb6b5e10f164c0191d51cd773f173' LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'melv'
 LIMIT 1
  Relation Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "relations".* FROM "relations" WHERE "relations"
."owner" = $1 AND "relations"."character" = 1 AND "relations"."type" = 'friend'
LIMIT 1  [["owner", 2]]
  Relation Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "relations".* FROM "relations" WHERE "relations"
."owner" = $1 AND "relations"."character" = 1 AND "relations"."type" = 'freq' LI
MIT 1  [["owner", 2]]
  Relation Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "relations".* FROM "relations" WHERE "relations"
."owner" = $1 AND "relations"."character" = 2 AND "relations"."type" = 'freq' LI
MIT 1  [["owner", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_edit_relation.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_relation.html.erb (14.0ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (23.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Relation Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "relations".* FROM "relations" WHERE "relations"
."owner" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_aside.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 299ms (Views: 290.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see an empty `<div id="relation></div>` in the page? Or nothing at all where the partial was supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the rendering ERB tag:

```
<%= render 'layouts/relation' unless current_user?(@user) %>
```

Comment: Thanks @depa . Now there's an empty div with no content. Can you see my edit above please?

Comment: If my answer solved your initial problem, then please accept it as the right answer. If you have other problems, the way to get them looked at is to open new questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `=` here--

```
<%= render 'layouts/relation' unless current_user?(@user) %>
```

Calling `render` will still generate the string, which is why you are seeing it in your logs; without the equals sign it's not going to appear on the page.

Answer (score 0):

So from your layouts/relation partial you're rendering another partial (layouts/edit_relation), right? Maybe that's where the problem is.